# Building XCode UI with storyboard + struct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, storyboard

I'm trying to update my app's StoreKit functionality.  My existing app uses storyboards to build UI.  The app I'm learning from (https://www.raywenderlich.com/15410082-storekit-testing-in-xcode-12-getting-started) and merging uses a struct based approach.  Is it possible to combine the two?  This video does a better job of explaining my problem and a few things I've tried... https://youtu.be/IdIR-eYOTUw

Comment: By sturct-based you mean SwiftUI right? Yes, you can use StoreKit in both SwiftUI and UIKit

Comment: Nice video btw.

Comment: Yes, SwiftUI is the "struct based approach", but didn't know what to call it.  So, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, (https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/integrating-swiftui-with-uikit) check out the link it explains it easily/

Comment: This looks like it'll do it.  Let me try...  I think one reason why I couldn't find something like this is above... I didn't know what to call SwiftUI vs UIKit.

Comment: https://youtu.be/k0o9BriMfb0
That did it!  I created another video with the implemented solution.  Thanks so much, that link helped a lot!